# How does Google Talk get current Music track?

Tags: .net, google-talk

How does Google Talk get the current song played? Can I do this using .net?

Edit : Looks like every player has its own SDK for use

**Winamp** : Here is a good thread about the clas to be used : http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?postid=2481680

**iTunes** :http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html

**Windows Media Player** : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmedia/default.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a consistent way of doing this, but I think that both iTunes and Windows Media Player have COM interfaces, which you can use for this sort of thing.

- http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmedia/default.aspx

Comment: How does Gtalk get Winamp's track ;-) they code for every player?

Comment: Both of those links redirect to useless landing pages now.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a plug-in for your media player. I suspect this plug-in is a COM component and exposes a COM interface for Google Talk to interface with and extract the information. If it is COM, then you should be able to do a similar thing using .NET.